# Python Голосовой Ассистент

Tags: python, windows

Решил написать своего голосового ассистента. Взял этот код и стал переделывать под себя. Все прекрасно работало, через какое то время Голосовой ассистент перестал работать. Вначале говорит приветствие, должен слушать, но ничего не происходит. Это исходник, даже он перестал работать. Все модули установлены, все должно работать. На переделанном убрал pygame и gtts, поставил pyttsx3, все работало хорошо. Как теперь быть не знаю. Код запускал и через Sublime 3, и VS code, и PyCharm. Что посоветуете?

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS

import pygame
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()

import os
import sys
import time
import datetime
import logging
import webbrowser
import subprocess

class Speech_AI:

    def __init__(self):
        self._recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        self._microphone = sr.Microphone()

        
        now_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        self._mp3_name = now_time.strftime("%d%m%Y%I%M%S")+".mp3"
        self._mp3_nameold='111'

    def work(self):
        print("Минутку тишины, пожалуйста...")
        with self._microphone as source:
            self._recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

        try:
            while True:
                print("Скажи что - нибудь!")
                with self._microphone as source:
                    audio = self._recognizer.listen(source)
                print("Понял, идет распознавание...")
                try:
                    statement = self._recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="ru_RU")
                    statement=statement.lower()

                    # Команды для открытия различных внешних приложений

                    if((statement.find("калькулятор")!=-1) or (statement.find("calculator")!=-1)):
                        self.osrun('calc')
                               
                    if((statement.find("блокнот")!=-1) or (statement.find("notepad")!=-1)):
                        self.osrun('notepad')
                             
                    if((statement.find("paint")!=-1) or (statement.find("паинт")!=-1)):
                        self.osrun('mspaint')

                    if((statement.find("browser")!=-1) or (statement.find("браузер")!=-1)):
                        self.openurl('http://google.ru', 'Открываю браузер')
 
                    # Команды для открытия URL в браузере
                    
                    if(((statement.find("youtube")!=-1) or (statement.find("youtub")!=-1) or (statement.find("ютуб")!=-1) or (statement.find("you tube")!=-1)) and (statement.find("смотреть")==-1)):                        
                        self.openurl('http://youtube.com', 'Открываю ютуб')
 
                    if(((statement.find("новости")!=-1) or (statement.find("новость")!=-1) or (statement.find("на усть")!=-1)) and ((statement.find("youtube")==-1) and (statement.find("youtub")!=-1) and (statement.find("ютуб")==-1) and (statement.find("you tube")==-1))):
                        self.openurl('https://www.youtube.com/user/rtrussian/videos', 'Открываю новости')
                         
                    if((statement.find("mail")!=-1) or (statement.find("майл")!=-1)):
                        self.openurl('https://e.mail.ru/messages/inbox/', 'Открываю почту')
                        
                    if((statement.find("вконтакте")!=-1) or (statement.find("в контакте")!=-1)):
                        self.openurl('http://vk.com', 'Открываю Вконтакте')

                    # Команды для поиска в сети интернет

                  
                    if((statement.find("найти")!=-1) or (statement.find("поиск")!=-1) or (statement.find("найди")!=-1) or (statement.find("дайте")!=-1) or (statement.find("mighty")!=-1)):
                        statement=statement.replace('найди', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('найти', '')
                        statement=statement.strip()
                        self.openurl('https://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=' + statement, "Я нашла следующие результаты")
                        
                    if((statement.find("смотреть")!=-1) and ((statement.find("фильм")!=-1) or (statement.find("film")!=-1))):
                        statement=statement.replace('посмотреть', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('смотреть', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('хочу', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('фильм', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('film', '')
                        statement=statement.strip()
                        self.openurl('https://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=Смотреть+онлайн+фильм+' + statement, "Выберите сайт где смотреть фильм")

                    if(((statement.find("youtube")!=-1) or (statement.find("ютуб")!=-1) or (statement.find("you tube")!=-1)) and (statement.find("смотреть")!=-1)):
                        statement=statement.replace('хочу', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('на ютубе', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('на ютуб', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('на youtube', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('на you tube', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('на youtub', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('youtube', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('ютуб', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('ютубе', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('посмотреть', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('смотреть', '')
                        statement=statement.strip()
                        self.openurl('http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + statement, 'Ищу в ютуб')


                    if((statement.find("слушать")!=-1) and (statement.find("песн")!=-1)):
                        statement=statement.replace('песню', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('песни', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('песня', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('песней', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('послушать', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('слушать', '')
                        statement=statement.replace('хочу', '')
                        statement=statement.strip()
                        self.openurl('https://my.mail.ru/music/search/' + statement, "Нажмите плэй")


                    # Поддержание диалога
                    
                    if((statement.find("до свидания")!=-1) or (statement.find("досвидания")!=-1)):
                        answer = "Пока!"
                        self.say(str(answer))
                        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
                            time.sleep(0.1)
                        sys.exit()
                    
                    print("Вы сказали: {}".format(statement))
                    
                except sr.UnknownValueError:
                    print("Упс! Кажется, я тебя не поняла, повтори еще раз")
                except sr.RequestError as e:
                    print("Не могу получить данные от сервиса Google Speech Recognition; {0}".format(e))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self._clean_up()
            print("Пока!")
        
    def osrun(self, cmd):
        PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    def openurl(self, url, ans):
        webbrowser.open(url)
        self.say(str(ans))
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def say(self, phrase):
        tts = gTTS(text=phrase, lang="ru")
        tts.save(self._mp3_name)

        # Play answer
        mixer.music.load(self._mp3_name)
        mixer.music.play()
        if(os.path.exists(self._mp3_nameold)):
            os.remove(self._mp3_nameold)
       
        now_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        self._mp3_nameold=self._mp3_name
        self._mp3_name = now_time.strftime("%d%m%Y%I%M%S")+".mp3"
        
        
    

    def _clean_up(self):
        def clean_up():
            os.remove(self._mp3_name)


def main():
    ai = Speech_AI()
    ai.work()

main()
```

Comment: а что именно не работает?

Comment: при запуске голосовой ассистент, который я переделал, говорит приветствие и начинает слушать команду, если ничего не сказано, то он просто печатает многоточие (в оригинале "Упс, кажется я вас не поняла"), но ничего не происходит, ни слушает, ни отвечает, ни реагирует никак

Comment: У вас переделанный код не работает или этот?

Comment: оба, работали оба варианта хорошо, но потом как будто просто резко перестало, то ли модули перестали работать, то ли чего. Интернет подключение есть, то есть SR должен спокойно работать.